# Aspxgridview : How to change the header caption width so it will fits the columns width?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have the following problem: on runtime I am changing the name of the columns caption (the grid is linked to a table and I don't want the user to see their original name). However I have one header caption which is too long - "Total Number of votes" which actually represents an integer not bigger than 4 digits. My question is how I can fix the header caption width ... in my case I want it to appear on two lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want column caption to wrap set column [HeaderStyle](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewHeaderStyleMembersTopicAll).[Wrap](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesAppearanceStyleBase_Wraptopic) to True.

```
<dxg:ASPxGridView runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <dxg:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Test" VisibleIndex="1" >
            <HeaderStyle Wrap="True"/>
        </dxg:GridViewDataColumn>
    </Columns>
</dxg:ASPxGridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add property ItemStyle-Width="your value"

```
Example for bound field

<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="150"/>
```

Comment: <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="NUMSEZ_M" ReadOnly="True" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="3" Width="8px"> in that case it works, but because the field name is changed on runtime it automatically fits to it.

Comment: Hi Andrey Have you checked with ItemStyle-Width="150" ?